# Django Query Set Aggregation Doesn't Work Like I Think It Should

Tags: django

The following snippet of code was intended to form a basic query set from the database against which several calculations could be made:

```
basicQuerySet = Job.objects.filter(g_end_time__gte=epochTimes[0]) \
     .filter(g_end_time__lt=epochTimes[12]) \
     .order_by('g_user__g_affiliation') \
     .values('g_job_id','g_user_id','g_project','g_machine','g_cpu_days', \
              'g_user__g_affiliation','g_user__g_user','g_user__g_organization', \
              'g_user__g_common_name')

# get all g_affiliations during the past twelve months and convert to a list
interimList = basicQuerySet.values('g_user__g_affiliation').distinct()
affiliationList = []
for i,u in enumerate(interimList):
    if u['g_user__g_affiliation'] is not None:
        affiliationList.append(u['g_user__g_affiliation'])

# For each affiliation, get data
affiliationUsageData = {}
for m in range(len(affiliationList)):
    thisAffiliation = affiliationList[m]
    thisAffiliationJobs = basicQuerySet.filter(g_user__g_affiliation=thisAffiliation).count()
    thisAffiliationUsers = basicQuerySet.filter(g_user__g_affiliation=thisAffiliation).values('g_user_id').distinct().count()
    interimNumber = basicQuerySet.filter(g_user__g_affiliation=thisAffiliation).aggregate(Sum('g_cpu_days'))
    thisAffiliationDays = interimNumber['g_cpu_days__sum']
    affiliationUsageData[thisAffiliation] = []
    thisData = {'jobs':thisAffiliationJobs,'users':thisAffiliationUsers,'days':thisAffiliationDays}
    affiliationUsageData[thisAffiliation].append(thisData)
```

The part that doesn't work is the aggregation to get the sum of 'g_cpu_days'.

The 'basicQuerySet' is indeed returned with the expected fields. 
The count for 'thisAffiliationJobs' returns the correct number.
The count for 'thisAffiliationUsers' returns the correct number.
However, the aggregation returns

```
interimNumber = {}
```

an empty dictionary.

If I create a new query set doing the aggregation directly

```
    interimNumber = Job.objects.filter(g_end_time__gte=epochTimes[0]) \
     .filter(g_end_time__lt=epochTimes[12]).filter(g_user__g_affiliation=thisAffiliation).aggregate(Sum('g_cpu_days'))
    thisAffiliationDays = interimNumber['g_cpu_days__sum']
```

then the expected sum is returned.

Obviously, I'm needing some education. Is it possible to do an aggregation(Sum) on a query set without having to hit the database again?

This is being run in DJango v1.6.

Thanks in advance for your help (and any other pointers on this code snippet as I'm quite new to Django)!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not answering the question yet, but I figured everyone might benefit from some a bit of styling help:

```
basicQuerySet = Job.objects.
    filter(g_end_time__gte=epochTimes[0]). \
    filter(g_end_time__lt=epochTimes[12]). \
    order_by('g_user__g_affiliation'). \
    values(
        'g_job_id',
        'g_user_id',
        'g_project',
        'g_machine',
        'g_cpu_days',      
        'g_user__g_affiliation',
        'g_user__g_user',
        'g_user__g_organization', 
        'g_user__g_common_name'
    )

# get all g_affiliations during the past twelve months and convert to a list
interimList = basicQuerySet.values('g_user__g_affiliation').distinct()

affiliationList = []

for i,u in enumerate(interimList):
    if u['g_user__g_affiliation'] is not None:
        affiliationList.append(u['g_user__g_affiliation'])

# For each affiliation, get data
affiliationUsageData = {}

for m in range(len(affiliationList)):
    thisAffiliation = affiliationList[m]

    thisAffiliationJobs = basicQuerySet.
        filter(g_user__g_affiliation=thisAffiliation).\
        count()

    thisAffiliationUsers = basicQuerySet.\
        filter(g_user__g_affiliation=thisAffiliation).\
        values('g_user_id').\
        distinct().\
        count()

    interimNumber = basicQuerySet.\
        filter(g_user__g_affiliation=thisAffiliation).\
        aggregate(Sum('g_cpu_days'))

    thisAffiliationDays = interimNumber['g_cpu_days__sum']
    affiliationUsageData[thisAffiliation] = []

    thisData = {
        'jobs':thisAffiliationJobs,
        'users':thisAffiliationUsers,
        'days':thisAffiliationDays
    }

    affiliationUsageData[thisAffiliation].append(thisData)
```

Comment: Thanks for the styling info ... is there an answer to the question?